# TableView not displaying array after adding object from Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

```
var test = [String]()
var array = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    test = ["1", "2"]
    var item = String()
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Restaurant")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                let data = object as PFObject
                item = String(data["name"])
                print(item)
                self.array.append(item)
            }
            print(self.array)
            print(self.array.count)
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

When I use "test" array, it can be displayed. But if I were to use the other array, it does not displays anything. Not sure if there array was correctly added but on the output, it shows data.

This is the output for print:

```
PerBacco
MACA Restaurant
["PerBacco", "MACA Restaurant"]
2
```

Comment: Did u check the count of other array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping you have set the tableView datasource + you have to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` to refresh tableView contents.

Answer (score 0):

With test, it can show data in the table because it is sync.

But with fetch data, it is async
You have to call `reloadData` after fetch the data

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                let data = object as PFObject
                item = String(data["name"])
                print(item)
                self.array.append(item)
            }
            print(self.array)
            print(self.array.count)
            tableView.realoadData() // here
        }
    }
```